# 改行コードを含むinput要素の値がalert関数で改行されない

Tags: javascript, jquery

例が悪かったので書き直します。

```html
<input type="hidden" id="testId" value="aaaaa\nbbbb">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
alert($("#testId").val())
</script>
```

この場合、alertで`aaaaa\nbbbb`と表示されてしまいます。
うまくalertで改行をする方法はありますか？

Comment: var a = "1111\n1111";
alert(a); IE上で試して改行できそうです。

Comment: <input type="hidden" id="testId" value="aaaaa\nbbbb">　このHidden変数の値ですが、動的に設定されたものかテストために手動に設定しましたか。　この値を見ると、alertの出力が正しいです（そもそも改行でないので）。

Comment: Hidden変数に改行文字埋める時、"aaa\\nbbb"の形で正しいだと思われます。

Comment: ありがとうございます。　hiddenからの取得は止めてグローバル変数に入れて対応しようと思います。

Comment: グローバル変数に入れて、PostBack時、値がNULLになる可能性がありますので、ご注意ください。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
alert($("testId").val().replace('\\n', '\n'));
```

で動くかと思います。

HTMLの属性値では `\` に特別な意味はありません。`<input type=hidden value="aaaaa&#x0a;bbbb">` とすれば改行がそのまま入ります。